# How to make blank/missing in Date_time column if the no.of frozen/repeating Date_time

Tags: mysql

How to make blank/missing in Date_time column if the no.of frozen/repeating Date_time is  equal to the no of desired Date_time record between previous correct Date_time and next correct Date_time in the time series (ROW_ID : 5,6,12,13)- Replace the frozen Date_time with the missing Date_time and keep record.

WE have the data in 15 mins interval
INPUT:

```
Row_id  Name    Date_time   Value
1   US  01-Nov-16 04:15:00  12
2   US  01-Nov-16 04:30:00  15
3   US  01-Nov-16 04:45:00  17
4   US  01-Nov-16 05:00:00  19

5   US  01-Nov-16 05:15:00  21
6   US  01-Nov-16 05:15:00  23

7   US  01-Nov-16 05:45:00  25

8   UK  06-Dec-16 09:15:00  27
9   UK  06-Dec-16 09:30:00  29
10  UK  06-Dec-16 09:45:00  31
11  UK  06-Dec-16 10:00:00  33

12  UK  06-Dec-16 10:15:00  35
13  UK  06-Dec-16 10:15:00  37

14  UK  06-Dec-16 10:45:00  39
```

OUTPUT:

```
Row_id  Name    Date_time   Value
1   US  01-Nov-16 04:15:00  12
2   US  01-Nov-16 04:30:00  15
3   US  01-Nov-16 04:45:00  17
4   US  01-Nov-16 05:00:00  19

5   US                      21
6   US                      23

7   US  01-Nov-16 05:45:00  25

8   UK  06-Dec-16 09:15:00  27
9   UK  06-Dec-16 09:30:00  29
10  UK  06-Dec-16 09:45:00  31
11  UK  06-Dec-16 10:00:00  33

12  UK                      35
13  UK                      37

14  UK  06-Dec-16 10:45:00  39
```

I have tried to get the output with below code

create table DS2 as

SELECT `date_time`,`value`, `name`, COUNT(*) - 2
FROM (
SELECT `date_time`,`value`, `name`, rn - seq AS grp
FROM (
  SELECT `date_time`,`value`, `name`,
         @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn,
         @seq := IF(@name = `name` And @val = `date_time`, @seq+1, 1) AS seq,
         @name := name,
         @val := date_time
  FROM DS1
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @seq := 0, @name = '', @val = 0) AS vars
  ORDER BY `date`) AS t ) AS s
  GROUP BY `date_time`, `name`, grp
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
;

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is what you list as OUTPUT what you are currently getting or your desired output? Show what you have tried.

Comment: i have tried first to identify the frozen/repeating values with this code

Comment: create table DS2 as

SELECT `date_time`,`value`, `name`, COUNT(*) - 2
FROM (
SELECT `date_time`,`value`, `name`, rn - seq AS grp
FROM (
  SELECT `date_time`,`value`, `name`,
         @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn,
         @seq := IF(@name = `name` And @val = `date_time`, @seq+1, 1) AS seq,
         @name := name,
         @val := date_time
  FROM DS1
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @seq := 0, @name = '', @val = 0) AS vars
  ORDER BY `date`) AS t ) AS s
  GROUP BY `date_time`, `name`, grp
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
;

Comment: Edit the question and add the code there pls. But accepr the formatting change first